# Clustering large number of time series in R or Matlab

Tags: r, machine-learning, matlab, pattern-recognition

I have a sales data of like 700K rows and three columns: Date (in dates), Store (as represented by numbers and there are more than 4800 different stores) and Sales amount (integer). Looks more like this:

```
Date      Sales  Store
6/9/2012   392   7184
6/9/2012   507   584
6/9/2012   1279  3060
6/9/2012   503   5572
```

My objective is to detect the similar patterns in Sales data, and which store is assigned to which pattern. There is a couple of pattern detection problems already asked but this time the patterns need to be linked by stores.

By 'similar pattern', I would consider two time series having more or less the same seasonality effects, same or similar numaber of times and dates for peaks, having an upward trend or so. But this is just my interpretation of similar.

I know how to use Minitab, but it is not useful for this question. I guess R or Matlab, would work but i'm really novice in this languages. Probabaly, R would help more in the following problems, I ll face like forecasting, goodness of fit etc. I need a general help on for instance which package to use and how. I know it sounds open ended, but heck that's all I can right now:/

Thanks!

Comment: Forget about packages. First clearly define the problem you are trying to solve (in business terms): why are you doing this, what is considered similar etc. then people can start helping you turning it into statistical methods

Comment: Hi @seanv507. I edited the original post to explain as much as I can. Unfortunately, this is an assignment work for a job interview and I dont have more info bu I need quick results:/

Comment: But the main idea is as follows: 1. Determine clusters of similar patterns. 2. Find which attributes are significant on classifying each store in one of the pattern classes. 3. For a new data, see how the model works for the classes, make goodness of fit tests and comment. That's all I can explain.

Comment: please keep adding clarification to main question only :).  what is meant by attributes (is there additional data eg location)?.  Don't get freaked out - just use common sense, there is no magic algorithm that finds 'patterns', you have to decide what to look at. Perhaps you could do a few plots (average sales by store bar chart, average sales by day of year bar chart, plot  sales by date for a couple of different stores), once you have got an idea of the patterns you can find you can apply a statistical method.

Comment: exactly. For the first part, i.e. finding the "pattern classes" only dates, store and sales amount. After this is done, there is another dataset, where there are like 5 more attributes, without an explanation. So I guess, after assigning the pattern classes to stores, I can test for significance of the atrributes in the second dataset. thanks for your help!